Refused to create a worker from 'blob:https://x/6a...293' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive
I have Blazor web assembly application (client + server) and keep Refused to create a worker   because it violates the following CSP directive.
It works locally but when I'm trying to publish my app and test published release (with self-signed ssl) I keep getting this annoying problem and I do not understand how to disable or modify CSP policy, so I can test publish version properly.
This is my current meta :
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * data: blob:; worker-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' * blob:;">

This code on server to ensure I will never will get any another SCP policies from server.
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Security-Policy");
        await next.Invoke();
    });

But I still keep getting this error : 
And I don't even know If this error will go away if I will configure proper SSL connection since I installed my current self-signed certificate as trusted, and run chrome these parameters :
 --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://xxxx/

So I don't understand why I still have these errors.

Check your response headers in production for any CSPs present there. When you add another policy in meta, that can only make your policy stricter. You need to identify how the policy in production is set and modify it. Also, the blob: source needs to be added to script-src or worker-src.

I updated the original post with a new meta values. And server cant contain any CSP headers since I effectively removing any CSP headers in middleware as shown in code.
I dont now how to debug CSP policies. this would be very useful if there is some script or way to get all existing CSP policies.

Check headers on the network tab on the production responses. Additional production CSPs are likely applied after you remove, in web server, proxy or load balancer. There must be another policy there as the error message mentions elements that are not in the policy in meta.

The error was caused by Chrome extension.
